# Passing an argument on libpcap pcap_loop() callback

Tags: c, libpcap

Because I would like to make some tests with the [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.htm) and a small C program, I am trying to pass a structure from main() to got_packet(). After reading the libpcap tutorial, I had found this:

> The prototype for pcap_loop() is
>   below:

```
int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)
```

> The last argument is useful in some
>   applications, but many times is simply
>   set as NULL. Suppose we have arguments
>   of our own that we wish to send to our
>   callback function, in addition to the
>   arguments that pcap_loop() sends. This
>   is where we do it. Obviously, you must
>   typecast to a u_char pointer to ensure
>   the results make it there correctly;
>   as we will see later, pcap makes use
>   of some very interesting means of
>   passing information in the form of a
>   u_char pointer.

So according to this, it is possible to send the structure in got_packet() using the argument number 4 of pcap_loop(). But after trying, I get an error.

Here is my (bugged) code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 /* some line of code, not important */

 /* def. of the structure: */
 typedef struct _configuration Configuration;
 struct _configuration {
   int id;
   char title[255];
 };

 /* init. of the structure: */
 Configuration conf[2] = {
   {0, "foo"},
   {1, "bar"}};

 /* use pcap_loop with got_packet callback: */
 pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, &conf);
}

void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet)
{
 /* this line don't work: */
 printf("test: %d\n", *args[0]->id);
}
```

I get this kind of error after some tests:

```
gcc -c got_packet.c -o got_packet.o
got_packet.c: In function ‘got_packet’:
got_packet.c:25: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’
```

Do you see how can I edit this code in order to pass *conf* (with is a array of configuration structure) in got_packet() function?

Many thanks for any help.

Regards

Comment: `( (Configuration*)args )[0]->id` ???

Comment: Thank you for your answer ; after trying it's not working... 
$ make
gcc -c got_packet.c -o got_packet.o
got_packet.c: In function ‘got_packet’:
got_packet.c:28: error: ‘Configuration’ undeclared (first use in this function)
got_packet.c:28: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
got_packet.c:28: error: for each function it appears in.)
got_packet.c:28: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
got_packet.c:94: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness
make: *** [got_packet.o] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the structure outside of main() and cast *args* in got_packet() like:

```
Configuration *conf = (Configuration *) args;
printf ("test: %d\n", conf[0].id);
```

Answer (score 6):

I rewrite Your code, it is now compile without any error:

```
#include <pcap.h> 

typedef struct {
  int id;
  char title[255];
} Configuration;

void got_packet( Configuration args[], const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet){
  (void)header, (void)packet;
  printf("test: %d\n", args[0].id);
}

int main(void){
  Configuration conf[2] = {
    {0, "foo"},
    {1, "bar"}};

  pcap_loop(NULL, 0, (pcap_handler)got_packet, (u_char*)conf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compile the above code.

install libpcap  --> sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev

then --> gcc got_packet.c -lpcap -o got_packet.o